# Bootstrap3 Tabs - Tab1 to Tab2 works. Tab2 to Tab 3 does not

Tags: jquery, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle

I've given up searching for an answer after 3h of online research. I'm hoping someone could help me please. I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.1 with jquery 1.11.1. In total, I have 3 tabs, each with different content. When I toggle from tab1 to tab2 it works perfectly. When I toggle from tab2 to tab3, tab3 seems to be displaying the exact same content as tab2, without content in tab3. After I added content to tab3, the text and text field were way off.... meaning tab3 displayed the exact content as tab2 AND displayed the new content outside of my tab-content. (dropped it below and outside of the tab-content area). I'm not sure what the cause could be?  Thanks for your input / help.

Here's my code:

```
<div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <h2 id = "center">PLUS HUNDREDS OF PRIZES INCLUDING<br/><a href="http://www.shop.canada.nhl.com/home/index.jsp">Shop.Canada.NHL.com</a> GIFT CARDS AND MONDELEZ SNACKS.</h2>
    <h3 id = "center-cap">share how you get game ready by photo,<br/> video or written description to be entered daily.</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="left-col">
  <div class = "col-lg6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

    <h4 id="text-cap">submit for a chance to win:</h4>

    <!--Tabs-->
<div class="tabbable">         
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
     <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" id="glyph-align"></span><br/>IMAGE</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link" id="glyph-align"></span><br/>SOCIAL</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" id="glyph-align"></span><br/>TEXT</a></li>
   </ul>
<div class="tab-content">

   <!---IMAGE tab -->
   <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
    <h4 id="center-cap-grey">browse from your desktop.</h4>

    <!-- File Upload Button-->
    <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
    <input type="file" ></span>
    <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="comment-box">
    <h4 id="text-cap-grey">share your story<br/> for an entry:</h4>
    <textarea rows="3" cols="38" maxlength="200" placeholder="(MAXIMUM OF 200 WORDS)" id="comments"></textarea>
     </div>                        
</div><!-- .tab-pane tab1 -->

    <!--SOCIAL LINK tab-->
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
    <h4 id="text-cap-grey2">paste your social medial link here:</h4>
    <input type="url" name="socialLink" placeholder="http://" size="35" id="socialLink" />
    <h4 id="text-cap-grey">social media<br/><small>(maximum of 200 words)<small></h4>
    </div><!-- .tab-pane tab2 -->

    <!-- TEXT tab -->
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
    <textarea rows="5" cols="38" maxlength="200" placeholder="(MAXIMUM OF 250 WORDS)" id="comments"></textarea>
    <h4 id="text-cap-grey">tell us more about you.</h4>
    </div><!-- .tab-pane tab3 -->

    </div><!-- .tab-content -->
 </div><!-- .tabbable -->

</div><!-- .col -->
</div><!-- .row -->
```

Comment: Always run your HTML through a validator first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have placed #tab3 into #tab2 div

Instead of this:

```
<small>(maximum of 200 words)<small>
```

Correct to this:

```
<small>(maximum of 200 words)</small>
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/odfa2sfd/)

Comment: sigh... as small (pun intended) and simple as that. lol THANK you!! Guess i just needed additional eyes on this. :)

Answer (score -1):

You missed closing a `<small>` tag. It is working now.

Check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0n7zL91x/1/)

```
<small>(maximum of 200 words)</small>
```